# Google Maps: Unable to get property 'lat' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the coordinates value of user's marker but for some reason the marker doesn't have lat and lng?! Error in console says: Unable to get property 'lat' of undefined or null reference. Why isn't my code working? I just want to save the coordinates in two hidden inputs in order to get them in PHP $_POST later.

html

```
                <div class="">
                    <input id="ciudad" name="ciudad" class="ciudad" type="text"
                           placeholder="Ciudad" ng-model="ciudad" required>
                    <div id="map"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="distance" size="31" value="31">
                    <input type="hidden" id="lat" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" id="lng" value="">
                </div>
```

js

```
// GOOGLE MAP
function initMap() {

    // MAP
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            center: { lat: 40.3302959, lng: -3.7387955 },
            zoom: 5
        });


    var locationInput = document.getElementById('ciudad');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(locationInput);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(locationInput);

    // MARKER
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map
    });


    var searchArea = '';

    // CIRCLE
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        radius: parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1609.3, //convert miles to meters
        strokeColor: "#7ED9C3",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#7ED9C3',
        fillOpacity: 0.4
    });
    circle.setMap(null);

    // PLACE CHANGED FUNCTION
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed',
        function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
            }

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                map.setZoom(9);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(9);
            }

            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

            // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
            searchArea = place.geometry.location;
            marker.setPlace({
                placeId: place.place_id,
                location: place.geometry.location
            });

        // Coordinates
                marker.position = marker.getPosition();
        var lat = marker.position.lat().toFixed(6);
        var lng = marker.position.lng().toFixed(6);
        getCoords(lat, lng);


            // Clear last circle
            circle.setMap(null);

            // Draw a circle around the radius
            circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: searchArea,
                radius: parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1609.3, //convert miles to meters
                strokeColor: "#7ED9C3",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#7ED9C3',
                fillOpacity: 0.4
            });
            circle.setMap(map);

            // Perform search over radius
            var request = {
                location: map,
                radius: parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1609.3, //convert miles to meters
                keyword: "coffee",
                rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE
            };

            service.nearbySearch(request, searchArea);
        });

        // COORDINATES
        function getCoords(lat, lng) {

           // Reference input html element with id=”lat”.
           var coords_lat = document.getElementById('lat');

           // Update latitude text box.
           coords_lat.value = lat;

           // Reference input html element with id=”lng”.
           var coords_lng = document.getElementById('lng');

           // Update longitude text box.
           coords_lng.value = lng;
        }
}
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object`

Comment: Yeah I'm not getting this error now after deleting the first 'center' under 'circle', but the one error 'Unable to get property 'lat' of undefined or null reference' still persists. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in an invalid `center` to `google.maps.Circle`

`center` needs to be a google.maps.LatLng object or a [LatLng Object Literal](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal)

```
var searchArea = '';

// CIRCLE
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: searchArea,
```

Just leave out your `center` entirely **at this point in your code**, because you are calling `setCenter` on your cicle below when you get your result anyway.

**Edit**

Your error is coming from these lines:

```
marker.position = marker.getPosition();
var lat = marker.position.lat().toFixed(6);
var lng = marker.position.lng().toFixed(6);
getCoords(lat, lng);
```

You're doing a bunch of unnecessary stuff. You already have the `lat` and `lng` from `place.geometry.location` so remove all that stuff replace it with:

```
getCoords(place.geometry.location.lat(),place.geometry.location.lng());
```

This line:

```
marker.position = marker.getPosition()
```

is very confusing (and is returning null). But I'm also assuming that google doesn't return a `LatLng` object from `marker.getPosition()` if you use `market.setPlace()` to position the marker instead of `market.setPosition()`. In any case, you don't need it.

Comment: This isn't right? searchArea = place.geometry.location; The circle does work, well it worked before I wrote the coordinates code, if I take it out the circle around any given marker does work fine. What should I do?

Comment: Look at your own code that I copied and pasted. You are setting searchArea equal to an empty string, and then setting the circle to have the center of it. Leave out the `center` entirely.

Comment: Okay I removed center under circle. Still getting the same error though, and the circle isn't displayed (even though it does work fine if I remove the coordinates bit of code).

Comment: Re-post your modified code. You only need to remove the center from the very first part where you declare `var circle...`

Comment: Oh so I only should remove the first 'center' under Circle? Just edited it. Still same error tho

Comment: @Evan - see my edit. You're right it was coming from your coordinates lines.

Comment: Thank you! I don't see the error anymore and the circle is back! The problem is that this code isn't giving me the coordinates, it literally returns "function (){return a}" and "function (){return b}"

Comment: I can see the new error: 'InvalidValueError: in property location: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number'. I've tried parseFloat(), setting input to number, setting it to text, using "" + lat, etc. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if the code just doesn't work?

Comment: My bad - geometry.location must be a google.maps.LatLng object - just use `.lat()` and `.lng()` instead of `.lat` and `.lng`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `marker.setPlace` to define the marker's location.  Apparently when you do that `marker.getPosition` returns undefined.  You can get the location you set by using `marker.getPlace().location`.

```
  // Coordinates
  var latLng = marker.getPlace().location;
  var lat = latLng.lat().toFixed(6);
  var lng = latLng.lng().toFixed(6);
```

(you also have some other errors downstream in your code, i.e. `searchArea` is not a function)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j8rzeujx/1/)

[image: screen shot of resulting map]

**code snippet:*

```js
// GOOGLE MAP
var map;

function initMap() {

  // MAP
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 40.3302959,
      lng: -3.7387955
    },
    zoom: 5
  });


  var locationInput = document.getElementById('ciudad');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(locationInput);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(locationInput);

  // MARKER
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });


  var searchArea = '';

  // CIRCLE
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    // center: searchArea,
    radius: parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1609.3, //convert miles to meters
    strokeColor: "#7ED9C3",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#7ED9C3',
    fillOpacity: 0.4
  });
  circle.setMap(null);

  // PLACE CHANGED FUNCTION
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed',
    function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        return;
      }

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        map.setZoom(9);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(9);
      }

      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
      searchArea = place.geometry.location;
      marker.setPlace({
        placeId: place.place_id,
        location: place.geometry.location
      });

      // Coordinates
      var latLng = marker.getPlace().location;
      var lat = latLng.lat().toFixed(6);
      var lng = latLng.lng().toFixed(6);
      getCoords(lat, lng);


      // Clear last circle
      circle.setMap(null);

      // Draw a circle around the radius
      circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: searchArea,
        radius: parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1609.3, //convert miles to meters
        strokeColor: "#7ED9C3",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#7ED9C3',
        fillOpacity: 0.4
      });
      circle.setMap(map);

      // Perform search over radius
      var request = {
        location: searchArea,
        radius: parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1609.3, //convert miles to meters
        keyword: "coffee",
        rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE
      };

      service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    });

  // COORDINATES
  function getCoords(lat, lng) {

    // Reference input html element with id=”lat”.
    var coords_lat = document.getElementById('lat');

    // Update latitude text box.
    coords_lat.value = lat;

    // Reference input html element with id=”lng”.
    var coords_lng = document.getElementById('lng');

    // Update longitude text box.
    coords_lng.value = lng;
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map,
.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div class="map">
  <input id="ciudad" name="ciudad" class="ciudad" type="text" placeholder="Ciudad" ng-model="ciudad" required>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <input type="hidden" id="distance" size="31" value="31">
  <input type="hidden" id="lat" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="lng" value="">
</div>
```